# Temporarily override output stream behavior

Tags: c++, iostream, pretty-print, ostream, idioms

Suppose I have a vector of chars (or just an iterator pair) which I want to print to an ostream. Now, I don't just want it printed - I want it to have specific kinds of spacing, I want a different representation of char values than just blurting them out to the terminal (say, both the char if it's printable and the escaped 2-digit or hex code.

Now I don't want to write my own custom code beyond the bare minimum - i.e. just a bit of glue and

```
void foo(ostream& os, char c) {
    os << c << ' ' << as_hex(c);
}
```

(which is like a custom overload for operator<< without the return.)

I do not want to have to loop over the vecotr, and for each character to manually call the abve I want it to behave and look as though I'm just  pipe my vector to my outoput stream, after having **temporarily** changed the latter's attributes. But occasionally I want the stream to go back to behaving normally, even for the same vector.

Can this be done reasonably/idiomatically?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you know about operator overloading and your main problem is to how tell operator which formatting option to use, i.e. how to store arbitrary information in stream.

Anything derived from `std::ios_base` (all standard stream classes) has [`.iword()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) method which returns reference to `long` from some internal storage and [`.pword()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/pword), which returns reference to `void*`. Unique index for these calls can be aquired through call to [`std::ios_base::xalloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc)

Example of using stream storage to change behaviour of output operation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int vprint_index = std::ios_base::xalloc();

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::vector<char> vec)
{
    if (out.iword(vprint_index) == 0) {
        for(char c: vec)
            out << c;
        return out;
    }
    out.iword(vprint_index) = 0;
    out << '{';
    bool first = true;
    for(char c: vec) {
        if(!first)
            out << ", ";
        first = false;
        out << c;
    }
    return out << '}';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> vector {'f', 'o', 'o'};
    std::cout << vector << '\n';
    std::cout.iword(vprint_index) = 1;
    std::cout << vector << '\n';
    std::cout << vector << '\n';
}
```

> foo
>   {f, o, o}
>   foo

Comment: This does not do the trick, since I need the overload to be *temporary* - I need to be able to switch it on or off.

Comment: @einpoklum Add `std::cout.iword(vprint_index) = 0;` after you done with it. If you need it to work only on one operation (non-sticky manipulator), have operator clear it itself.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot "temporarily overriding" stream formatting could mean one of two things: either a series of one-shot manipulations (where the stream automatically reverts after each invocation - my interpretation), or a stateful change (apparently yours). I'm upvoting your answer as it correctly finds a place to store the state (for the latter interpretation). As the question is badly phrased and unclear, it's impossible to ascertain the original intent (and it doesn't really matter much).

Answer (score 1):

For the overloading to be temporary, I thought it would be nice to do some stuff like in `iomanip`. This will allow to do stuff like

```
int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b'}; 
    /* v should be printed using foo_vector_print, perhaps
    *    next invocation should use a different format. */
    std::cout << foo_vector_print() << v << std::endl; 
}
```

The idea is to have something of the form:

```
 stream << manip << vector;
```

where

- `stream << manip` will return an object of a class storing a reference to the stream.
- `... << vector` will print using a specific format, then return a reference to the original stream.

The following program shows how to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


namespace detail
{

// A dummy class in detail namespace, simply records the original ostream object.
struct foo_vector_printer_imp
{
    std::ostream *m_os;
};

};


// This particular implementation simply prints out the vectors size.
std::ostream &operator<<(detail::foo_vector_printer_imp imp, const std::vector<char> &v)
{
    *imp.m_os << v.size();

    return *imp.m_os;
}


struct foo_vector_print{};


/* The result of piping a foo_vector_print into an ostream, 
*    is a foo_vector_printer_imp object recording the ostream */
detail::foo_vector_printer_imp operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo_vector_print &)
{
    detail::foo_vector_printer_imp imp;
    imp.m_os = &os;
    return imp;
}


int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b'}; 
    std::cout << foo_vector_print() << v << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: I'd guess `setw` is simpler, as it just takes a reference to a stream, calls a method of it, and returns a reference to the same object. The answer above returns a different object to a different class "pushing" the original stream, then the next `<<` "pops" the original stream.

Comment: @einpoklum You can call `setw` and output your stuff in two different statements. There you _have_ to chain your operators. So it is slightly different, but in most cases not really noticeable.

Comment: Essentially you've just wrapped a call to `print_in_fancy_way` to an operator<< and a helper gadget. That might be part of a solution, but it's not _a_ solution.

Comment: No, it actually *is* a solution. Following the piping of the modifier, you can't pipe something except the vector; following the piping of the vector, the effect of the modifier is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have to write your custom code *somewhere*. The contents of your vector aren't going to write to a `std::ostream` all by themselves.

You're really asking, from the looks of it, how to be able to use the `<<` operator to operate on a `std::vector<char>`. The following example should get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const std::vector<char> &v)
{
    // Fill in the blanks here.
    return o;
}

// Example:

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v;

    std::cout << v;

    return 0;
}
```